# How to open this smoke detector in order to change battery?

Tags: smoke-detectors, alarm

I need to change battery for my home smoke detector, but I have no idea how to open this model.

I found many video tutorial on google, but have not seen any model similar to this one.

Does anyone have experience on this model?

[image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HEMS, the vendor, answered my enquiry.

There is actually a clip (first image in the original question) with an arrow mark on it.
The problem is that the mark is uncoloured, very difficult to be noticed from where I stand.

Push the clip to the left to release the lock, then pull down the whole thing.

[image]

You will find the latch hardly slides: it has to move about 1mm and then pull it down **gently** because the hook has a habit of snapping off.

Comment: Do you have any idea how long the battery will last for?

Comment: @Vincent, it's recommended to replace the battery every year. But it actually lasts much longer. When the battery is nearly flat, the device will beep every few minutes to draw your attention.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is that you try pressing in (or up) on these two tabs:

[image]

[image]

And then that the lower part of the unit will hinge down. The hinge edge being along here:

[image]

Comment: This sounds right. If all else fails, it appears to be a HEMS unit from Australia. You could contact the manufacturer [here](http://www.hemelect.com.au/autopage.php?page=Smoke+Detectors&supcat=Light+Fittings%2C+Lamps%2C+Smoke+Detectors+%26+Accessories)

Comment: thanks very much. I tried very hard on that two tabs, but they are not moveable.

Comment: Thank you @bib for pointing me to the vendor, too hard for me to find out the vendor on internet. I will update the question if I got positive feedback from them.

Comment: @bib, thx. HEMS solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Just did it by pushing the bottom part a bit towards the ceiling and meanwhile sliding the clip to the left which is the arrow pointing direction - and yay it easily was opened.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for this, I have an alarm similar to the one in the first photo. You only have to slide the clip a very little way while pulling the cover down from the side of the clip to open it up. Had to get a torch to see the arrow on the clip.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply grasping the lower portion of the detector unit and then try to turn it left or right. It may turn a short distance and then simply pull straight down.

AC Powered smoke detectors like this almost always have a plastic receiver piece that screws to the ceiling / electrical box. The AC power wires attach to a short harness and connector assembly that passes through a hole on the receiver plate. This connector then attaches to the top side of the detector unit. At installation the detector unit has fingers that match up with slots in the receiver plate. Then unit is simply pushed up into place and then rotated 25 - 35 degrees to lock it into place on the receiver piece.

My suggested removal procedure is the reverse of this common installation procedure.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and your time. I did see few models similar to your description on google, but this one is different.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar one mine says slide to remove.[image]

[image]